# error: failed to solve: failed commit on ref : unexpected status: 400 Bad Request

Tags: amazon-web-services, git, circleci

I am trying to build projects using **Circle CI** [aws-ecr-orb](https://github.com/CircleCI-Public/aws-ecr-orb) to push to a private repository in AWS.

I get the error below:

```
#16 exporting to image
#16 sha256:7dd518c28ca8d9b4a669654c56822c182f0329e5b5897d4cc9241360bd781320
#16 pushing layers 3.4s done
#16 pushing manifest for ************.dkr.ecr.*********.amazonaws.com/***********:latest@sha256:73bcacc452698bb9bc03feb199ffde7d62016bfb46b783c436f9c8e5a8a69e32
#16 pushing manifest for ************.dkr.ecr.*********.amazonaws.com/***********:latest@sha256:73bcacc452698bb9bc03feb199ffde7d62016bfb46b783c436f9c8e5a8a69e32 0.3s done
#16 ERROR: failed to push ************.dkr.ecr.*********.amazonaws.com/***********:latest: failed commit on ref "manifest-sha256:73bcacc872698bb9bc03feb199ffde7d62016bfb46b783c436f9c8e5a8a69e32": unexpected status: 400 Bad Request
------
 > exporting to image:
------
error: failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to push ************.dkr.ecr.*********.amazonaws.com/***********:latest: failed commit on ref "manifest-sha256:73bcacc872698bb9bc03feb199ffde7d62016bfb46b783c436f9c8e5a8a69e32": unexpected status: 400 Bad Request

Exited with code exit status 1
CircleCI received exit code 1
```

I'm trying to understand why the error is coming up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally figured out the issue.

The issue was caused because I changed the tag mutability setting for the repository to `IMMUTABLE`.

All I had to do was to change the tag mutability setting for the repository to `MUTABLE`.

In Terraform AWS ECR module, I just had to add the settings below to the resource:

```
repository_image_tag_mutability        = "MUTABLE"
```

**Resources**: [error: failed to solve: failed commit on ref : unexpected status: 400 Bad Request #200](https://github.com/CircleCI-Public/aws-ecr-orb/issues/200#issuecomment-1122429933)

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, when I enable caching to ECR registry. The repo has "immutability" disabled, which should be the correct setting. Setting proveneance=false didn't help either. I had to disable caching again to be able run without errors.

Answer (score 10):

In case people arrive here because they see the same error when using BuildKit / buildx directly, e.g. like this

```
docker buildx build -t repo.example.com/my-app:latest --push .
```

please note that

> Buildx v0.10 enables support for a minimal SLSA Provenance attestation, which requires support for OCI-compliant multi-platform images. This may introduce issues with registry and runtime support (e.g. Google Cloud Run and Lambda). You can optionally disable the default provenance attestation functionality using --provenance=false

So,

```
docker buildx build -t repo.example.com/my-app:latest --push --provenance=false .
```

solves the issue.

Comment: Thank you, I have been trying to debug this for days before I found your answer. Setting `BUILDX_NO_DEFAULT_ATTESTATIONS=1` fixes it.

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing this issue, trying to use `--cache-to` with an ECR repo. The solution was to add these options to `--cache-to`:

```
mode=max,image-manifest=true,oci-mediatypes=true,type=registry,ref=
```

```bash
docker build -t <account-id>.dkr.ecr.<my-region>.amazonaws.com/buildkit-test:image \
--cache-to mode=max,image-manifest=true,oci-mediatypes=true,type=registry,ref=<account-id>.dkr.ecr.<my-region>.amazonaws.com/buildkit-test:cache \
--cache-from type=registry,ref=<account-id>.dkr.ecr.<my-region>.amazonaws.com/buildkit-test:cache .
```

As described here:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/announcing-remote-cache-support-in-amazon-ecr-for-buildkit-clients/